# Where can I find the SQL files of XAMPP in Linux?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, database, xampp

I lost access to my database and I only have the system files, how can I extract the data from my database (XAMPP)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will get all databases at "xampp/var/mysql".
You can copy complete folder to new setup and it will show you all databases.

Comment: Thank you @Puneet and how can I backup data files and restore with fresh mysql application core in xampp ?